# Script not working on inactive tab

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have script for geolocalization. It's working only when user is on website. When browser is miminalized or tab is inactive, script is not working. How can I fix it?

```
var int=self.setInterval(function(){getLocation()},2000);
function getLocation()
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}

function showPosition(position)
{
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log('Position: '+latitude+' '+longitude);
    $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    data : { latitude : latitude, longitude : longitude },
    url : "mylinktosaveposition",
    success : function(data){}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature built into browsers, there is no way to get around this! Browsers simply freeze or shut down scripts when they go inactive to increase performance on active tabs and reduce power usage on battery powered devices. I would recommend creating an app if you are looking into geotracing people for whatever reason. Take a look at ionic which is a framework on cordova which uses angular to built apps for ios and android in javascript/html like language.